# What permission do we need to use instead of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Android 13 app on Android 13 device?

Tags: android, react-native

What permission do we need to use instead of WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in Android 13 app on Android 13 device? I have read through the documentation but not able to get what permission we need to use. The function which needs this is a photo picker which access the images, before it used to ask for permission on Android 12, but once the app was upgraded to Android 13 and used on an Android 13 app, the photo picker stopped working. It uses the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE which is not required anymore. But what needs to be used instead of this?

The function is from a library - react-native-image-crop-picker

```js
    @ReactMethod
    public void openPicker(final ReadableMap options, final Promise promise) {
        final Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();

        if (activity == null) {
            promise.reject(E_ACTIVITY_DOES_NOT_EXIST, "Activity doesn't exist");
            return;
        }

        setConfiguration(options);
        resultCollector.setup(promise, multiple);
        initiatePicker(activity);
        permissionsCheck(activity, promise, Collections.singletonList(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), new Callable<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call() {
                
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `The function which needs this is a photo picker which access the images` can you post code of this function?

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions

Comment: @DivyangDivasaliwala thanks for pointing these out, I actually went through these granular permissions, I guess these are only for the purpose of Reading files, but here the requirement is to Write, as WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is used. For WRITE I could not find any alternative other than a new library 'Photo Picker' which is only supporting newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Use react-native-permissions for managing the permissions.
The [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions) are quite simple, kindly go through this.

Answer (score 1):

Some permission changes were required for this in the react-native-image-cropper library - https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/pull/1852